# Duplicate text from a file

Tags: c++

Having trouble. When I run this block of code it duplicates the last one posted and I have chalked it up to maybe being because there is a space at the end of the createFile which it may be reading but I am not for certain. The content of the file is: a a b b c c d d and it prints the d d twice.

```
             string fileName;
             string fileBirthday;
             string text;
             ifstream readFile("database.txt");
             while (readFile.good()) {
                 readFile >> fileName;
                 readFile >> fileBirthday;
                 tree.enterPerson(count, fileName, fileBirthday);
             }
             readFile.close();
```

```
void createTree::createFile(TreeNode *nodePtr, ofstream& file) {

    if (nodePtr != NULL) {
        if (nodePtr->left) {
            createFile(nodePtr->left, file);
        }
        file << nodePtr->name << " ";
        file << nodePtr->birthday << " ";
        if (nodePtr->right) {
            createFile(nodePtr->right, file);
        }
    }
    else {
        return;
    }

    }
```

```
void createTree::displayInOrder(TreeNode *nodePtr) {
    if (nodePtr) {
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->left);
        cout << nodePtr->name << " " << nodePtr->birthday << endl;
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->right);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] or no one could reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 4):

`while (readFile.good())` is flawed because the `eof` bit is not in general set until you actually try to read something from the stream.

Better, then, to write your code like this:

```
while (readFile >> fileName >> fileBirthday)
    tree.enterPerson(count, fileName, fileBirthday);
```

This works because `ifstream` has an implicit conversion to `bool` that returns `false` when the stream is no longer readable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no idea you could include it in the brackets. That helped.